# Getting more details about the likes on your facebook page

Tags: facebook

I want to run a competition on my facebook page on a given user who will like my page for instance, say the 100th user who likes this page get free service in this

I have checked everywhere even with the new facebook graph, I cant seems to see any more details about the user page as to when they didn it, or some sort of count to know that user is what number is terms of likes..

Anyone who knows a way or can assist?..

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done.  Sorry.  There is no way for you to get the 100th user who likes a Facebook page.

Maybe you make a fan gate application as a "Page Tab" application, where every 100th unique person visiting the fan-gated app gets something.

Comment: I think that’d be against policies for promotions on Facebook – you have to make sure that users who have already liked your page in the past have the same chance of winning as a user who just likes your page now to take part in that promotion.